# Deleting $key from array cleans the array

Tags: php

The following code uses an array in order to search if an ID in the array matches to `$rmid`. If true it removes the whole proper key.

```
$rmid = 1;
$data = $db['refs'];
// remove element
foreach( $data as $k => $v ) {
  if( in_array( $rmid, $v ) ) {
    unset( $data[$k] );
  }
}
```

Hovewer, if exactly `1` is passed to the `$rmid`, it deletes all keys from the array! Not the only one with `$rmid = 1`. What's wrong with my code?

EDIT

Opps. Right after posting I just realized:

```
if( $rmid == $v['id'] ) {
  unset( $data[$k] );
}
```

Thank you for your effort!

Comment: Can you show us what's in your array ?

Comment: Depends on what `$data` looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
if( in_array( $rmid, $v, true ) ) {
```

the third parameter enforces a === instead of a ==, 1 evaluates to true but so do most other things, loosely in PHP. [== works for comparing two things of the same type, but when it does type conversion it can have some strange quirks]